# Can't select the column 'TEXT' using php and oci?

Tags: php, oracle, escaping, oracle-call-interface

I'm working with a database that uses 'Text' as a column name.

According to the lists of [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621) and [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) keyword, 'Text' should be fine.

However,

```
 $selectStatement = @"SELECT customer_code, object_num, create_date, name, Text FROM obj_table ORDER BY create_date DESC FETCH NEXT :numRows rows only";
```

Will not work. It works perfectly if I don't select the Text column.

I get the following error: `Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in C:\xampp\htdocs\compare\index.php on line 52`

I have tried escaping text like `'Text'` or `` `Text` `` or `\'Text\'` or `"Text"` or using an alias like

```
 SELECT customer_code, object_num, create_date, name, t.Text FROM obj_table as 't' ORDER BY create_date DESC FETCH NEXT :numRows rows only;
```

But nothing seems to work. If I remove text, and add another column name, it works perfectly. So I think there must be something wrong with the Keyword 'Text'

Edit1: The query works perfectly in SQL Oracle Developer. Just not through PHP/OCI

Comment: In Oracle you use double quotes to quote the column name.

Comment: The issue turned out to be that TEXT was a CLOB :(

Comment: I've reopened the question since it was the wrong duplicate. You can post an answer now.